# apply calculations to column in php

Tags: javascript, php, database, calculated-columns

Hi I fetching some data from database and constructing the table.

```
foreach($data_array->LINEDETAILS as $data){
    if(empty($data->CREDITEDAMOUNT)){
        $data->CREDITEDAMOUNT=0;
    }
    $linetotal='';
    $linetotal = $data->LINEAMOUNT + $data->TAXAMOUNT;
    $column='<td>
                <input onclick="sum_value(\''.trim($data->LINEAMOUNT).'-'.$data->TAXAMOUNT.'\',this.checked)" type="checkbox" name="checkdata'.$i.'" id="checkdata'.$i.'" value="'.$data->CUSTOMERTRXLINEID.'"style="position: inherit;" checked  />
             </td>
             <td>'.$data->DESCRIPTION.'</td>
             <td>'.$data->ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT.'</td>
             <td>'.$data->CREDITEDAMOUNT.'</td><td>'.$data->LINEAMOUNT.'<input type="text" value="'.$data->LINEAMOUNT.'" hidden="true"></td>
             <td>'.$data->TAXAMOUNT.'</td><td>'.$linetotal.'</td>
             <td>
                   <select>
                      <option>--</option>
                      <option>%</option>
                      <option>Area</option>
                      <option>Period In Months</option>
                   </select>
             </td>
             <td><input type="text"></td>
             <td><input type="text"></td>';
    $row .= '<tr>'.$column.'</tr>';
    $grandtotal = $grandtotal + $data->LINEAMOUNT + $data->TAXAMOUNT;
    $i++;
}
```

This code returns one to many lines of data.
[image]

Each like has a dropdown of 3 value based upon which calculations will be done. If I select  as % and **Credit value** as 80%, the **approved line amount** should be calculated onblur 80% of **Eligible line amount**. 
I tried to set id's for each elements and do the math using JavaScript it won't calculate and give the result. it gives an error since ID of an element should be unique and since the elements are looped the ID also gets looped. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for : "onChange" of the dropdown value and then fetch the % value and calculate in your javascript code and display on the filed that is required, and mark the field as read-only if you want it "not" to be changed.

You can dynamically add id for each element as in the loop.. abd after that fetch all the records till the max value or iteration (say i)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on each input field. For eg.

```js
jQuery('.credit_val').change(function(){
var eligible = parseFloat(jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('.eligible_line').text());
var credit = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());

jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('.approve_amount').val(eligible*credit/100);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="eligible_line">1000</div> 
</td>
<td>
    <input class = "credit_val">
</td>
<td>
    <input class = "approve_amount">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="eligible_line">2000</div> 
</td>
<td>
    <input class = "credit_val">
</td>
<td>
    <input class = "approve_amount">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this. Since the elements are inside a loop same class applies to all the line elements. when on blur it will populate the same result for all other fields with same Class.

Comment: @hemanthkumar, that is not true. We are using jQuery(this) as reference to refer only the element on which this calculation will be performed. If you run my example, then you could see, both rows are calculating the result independently.